# React Yup validation for sum of length of two fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am new to React and yup validation. This is the entity

```
export interface ClientContact {
  names?: {
    firstName?: string;
    middleName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
  }[];
}
```

I don't want the name to be more than 75 characters i.e. sum of length of firstname, middlename and lastname cannot be more than 75.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    contacts: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        names: Yup.array().of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            firstName: Yup.string()
              .required('First Name is required.')
              .max(45, 'Only 45 characters allowed.'),
            middleName: Yup.string(),
            lastName: Yup.string()
              .required('Last Name is required.')
              .max(45, 'Only 45 characters allowed.'),
          })
        ),
     });
```

How may I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `test` method on the `names` Object:

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  contacts: Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
      names: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
          firstName: Yup.string()
            .required('First Name is required.')
            .max(5, 'Only 5 characters allowed.'),
          middleName: Yup.string(),
          lastName: Yup.string()
            .required('Last Name is required.')
            .max(5, 'Only 5 characters allowed.')
        // ADDITION >>
        }).test({
          message: 'The error message if length > 10',
          test: ({ firstName, middleName, lastName }) => {
            const len = firstName.length + middleName.length + lastName.length;
            console.log({ len });
            return len <= 10
          },
        })
        // << ADDITION
      )
    })
  )
});

schema
  .validate({ contacts: [
    { names: [{
      firstName: "John",
      middleName: "G.H.",
      lastName: "Doe"
    }] }
  ] })
  .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
  .then(() => console.log("valid"));
```

*( Changed to a total of `10` for quick testing purposes. )*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The error does occur and prevents the form from being submitted. Is there a way to retrieve the error message and whether the error has occurred  in the tsx file. I need to notify the user in the form that this error occured in the form.

Comment: Yes, you can indeed verify and retrieve the error but that's a whole new chapter. It depends on how you are using forms in your React app (e.g. via Formik, useForm, etc.). Depending on the library you pick check for the relevant documentation. Otherwise, you can just clal the validate() method on the submit event.

Comment: I've created a separate ticket for the retrieval of error message. Please answer that in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74126203/get-errormessage-in-react-tsx-page-for-yup-test