# Get errorMessage in react tsx page for yup.test()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I am new to react and yup. I've created a test in yup schema

```
export interface ClientContact {
  names?: {
    firstName?: string;
    middleName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
  }[];
}
```

I don't want the name to be more than 75 characters i.e. sum of length of firstname, middlename and lastname cannot be more than 75. This is the schema for that

```
Yup.object().shape({
        names: Yup.array().of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            firstName: Yup.string()
              .required('First Name is required.')
              .max(45, 'Only 45 characters allowed.'),
            middleName: Yup.string(),
            lastName: Yup.string()
              .required('Last Name is required.')
              .max(45, 'Only 45 characters allowed.'),
          }).test({
            test: ({ firstName, middleName, lastName }) => {
              return (firstName?.length ?? 0) + (middleName?.length ?? 0) + (lastName?.length ?? 0) <= 75;
            },
          })
        )
```

The test works and prevents the form from submitting.  The error does occur and prevents the form from being submitted. Is there a way to retrieve the error message and whether the error has occurred in the tsx file. I need to notify the user in the form that this error occured in the form.

Comment: So you're simply trying to validate a form?

Comment: The the validation works. The test() prevents the submission of form if sum of length of first, middle and last name is more than 75 characters. I need to notify the user in the form that this error occurred in the form.